# Как сделать, чтобы при повторном клике свойства блока возвращались?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть функция, которая при клике меняет свойства блока.
Как сделать так, чтобы при повторном клике свойства блока возвращались?

```js
function hideShadow() {
  var el = document.getElementById("shadow");
  el.style.boxShadow = "0 0 0 0";
  el.style.textShadow = "none";
}

function buttonName() {
  var x = document.getElementById("buttonChange");
  x.innerHTML = "Show shadow";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: pink;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.BoxShadow {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-shadow: 10px 5px 8px grey;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px blue, 0 0 20px 20px grey, 0 0 20px 30px #B0E0E6;
}

.button {
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 45px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="shadow" class="BoxShadow">SOLOLEARN</div>
  <div class="button">
    <button id="buttonChange" onclick="hideShadow(); 
     buttonName();">Hide shadow</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: как эти свойства устанавливаются изначально? `innerHTML` - никак не обратить, только сохранять предыдущий результат в переменную

Answer (score 3):

Самый лучший вариант, это не стили менять в js, а классы, что можно сделать в css, должно быть сделано в css, я тебе добавил стили, увидешь...  A в JS просто добавояешь или удаляешь  класс... А что касается кнопки, простой тернарник...

```js
var shadow = document.getElementById("shadow"),
  buttonChange = document.getElementById("buttonChange");;
/*в место onclick в html лучше использовать  addEventListener */
buttonChange.addEventListener('click', function() {
  /*classList.toggle меняет класс если ето удаляет если нет добавляет */
  shadow.classList.toggle('shadow');
/* а это тернанрный оператор просто аналог if с одним условием если Hide shadow
меняеи на Show shadow  если нет меняем на Hide shadow
*/
  buttonChange.innerHTML == 'Hide shadow' ?
    buttonChange.innerHTML = 'Show shadow' :
    buttonChange.innerHTML = 'Hide shadow';
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: pink;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.BoxShadow {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-shadow: 10px 5px 8px grey;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px blue, 0 0 20px 20px grey, 0 0 20px 30px #B0E0E6;
}

.BoxShadow.shadow {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-shadow: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;
}

.button {
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 45px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="shadow" class="BoxShadow">SOLOLEARN</div>
<div class="button">
  <button id="buttonChange">Hide shadow</button>
</div>
```

Comment: как минимум нужны пояснения, что происходит в коде в ответе. Ну и если вдруг поменяется background по умолчанию, надо будет лезть в код и менять строку

Comment: Есть кнопка, которой присвоено событие onclick="hideShadow(); buttonName();"
Если нажать на кнопку, удаляется тень блока и надпись на самой кнопке. Мне надо, чтобы при повторном клике вернулась тень и надпись на кнопке. Сори парни, но ваш ответ мне не понятен, но спасибо, что откликнулись. Новачку всегда  тяжко)

Comment: @Adel, выдложи сюда и html  css, что бы выдеть общую картину, и я тебе ответ с пояснениями напишу...

Comment: добавила код html/css

Comment: @Adel, разобралась?

Comment: только хотела писать слова благодарности, но вылезла ошибка
"Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"
https://www.screencast.com/t/pzftuKunk3

Comment: но все же спасибо, попробую разобраться ;)

Comment: покажи скрины  html  css  jsты там что то с классами и ID напутала

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/yUPTqlzf
https://www.screencast.com/t/7I4Hg4nCZ
https://www.screencast.com/t/HJeQNJS1u
https://www.screencast.com/t/sS9zYTrVL

Comment: в твоих скринах не вижу подключенных стилей и JS. И  не забудь js в данном случае надо подключать перед закрывающимся тегом /body, а если ты данный скрипт подключила в head, то он вероятнее всего по этому и не работает и выдает ошибку

Answer (score -1):

Сначала запиши нужные свойства в переменную, потом измени, - когда будет нужно вернуть значения свойств - подставь из переменных